# how can i select corresponding element in a function in jquery?

Tags: jquery

say i have 20 div like this:

```
   <div id="b1"></div>
   <div id="b2"></div>
   <div id="b3"></div>
   <div id="b4"></div>
...
```

and 20 inpute:

```
<inpute id="in1"></inpute>
<inpute id="in2"></inpute>
<inpute id="in3"></inpute>
<inpute id="in4"></inpute>
...
```

now i want to do something like this:

```
  $('#b1').click(function(){
    $('#in1').fadeIn();
  });
  $('#b2').click(function(){
    $('#in2').fadeIn();
  });
....
```

so each div has to fade corresponding input. i have to repeat my code.
is there a way to select corresponding element dynamically? i want to have one function

**edit**:

it seems that i have to use class. by something like this:

```
$(this).index()
```

i can get the index of the clicked one. so my code:

```
$('.b').click(function(){
    $('.in('+ $(this).index() +')').FadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Seems like a case of "iditis". Use a common class and target elements by index, and everything will be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the element's ID and replace `b` with `in`:

```
$('div[id^=b]').click(function(){
    $('#' + this.id.replace('b', 'in')).fadeIn();
});
```

Or if both set of elements are in the same order, you can select the corresponding element via index:

```
var $inputs = $('input[id^=in]'); // you really should use a class
var $divs = $('div[id^=b]'); // you really should use a class
$divs.click(function(){
    $inputs.eq($divs.index(this)).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $('[id^=b').click(function(){
  $('#in' + this.id.replace('b','')).fadeIn().siblings().fadeOut();
 });
```